# What is the best way to achieve repeatable content with WordPress and ACF?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a website for a local builder and he asked me to create a 'Project' functionality where he could add a Project, fill in the information and add photos and then have a page called 'Projects' where the new project automatically goes on to the page which then links to a page about the project in more detail.

Using Advanced Custom Fields, how would I create something like this?

Do I use the Page system or do I create a custom ACF options page just for projects? Each Project will need its own page and the project title and image must be accessible from the page footer as 6 of the latest projects will be shown there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably not use Advanced Custom Fields for the projects but a custom post type called "Projects"

Register a Post Type

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Or Using a Plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

This will give you a new Projects section just like pages or posts and I would use Advanced Custom Fields to add fields to the projects so you can add additional information on the project such as photos and any other fields a project might require.

Custom Post Type archive pages are accessible via www.yoursite.com/projects which will list all of the projects using the default template one of

```
single.php
archive.php
```

depending on your theme then each single project will have it's own page too at www.yoursite.com/projects/project-name these will probably use one of

```
single.php
singular.php
index.php
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

You can create custom templates for both of these by creating files named

```
archive-projects.php
single-projects.php
```

The footer would be a different issue you'd need to loop through your projects using one of

```
get_pages();
get_posts();
WP_Query;
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query